# Change order of fields for @inproceedings type of references while using ieeetr bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, ieeetran

I am using the `ieeetr` bibliography style and have a specific problem concerning `@inproceedings` type of references.

My `tex` file is as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\cite{date2019classical}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{references.bib}

\end{document}
```

And my `bib` file is as follows:

```latex
@inproceedings{date2019classical,
    Author = {Date, Prasanna and Schuman, Catherine and Patton, Robert and Potok, Thomas},
    Booktitle = {Future of Inf. and Communication Conf.},
    Pages = {98--117},
    Title = {A Classical-Quantum Hybrid Approach for Unsupervised Probabilistic Machine Learning},
    Year = {2019}}
```

The compiled file looks like this:

[image]

The [IEEE Reference Guide](http://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/IEEE-Reference-Guide.pdf) requires that for conference proceedings, the  page numbers should appear at the very end (see "Conference Proceedings in Print (Paper Presented at a Conference)" section on page 6), i.e. the last part of the bibliography entry should be: `2019, pp. 98-117.`

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ieeetr` bibliography style dates back to the early 1980s. It's almost as old as very first version of LaTeX. As such, it no longer represents the *current* IEEE reference guide for how bibliographic entries should be formatted.

What to do? Very easy: switch to the `IEEEtran` bibliography style.

[image]

Observe that the `pages` field is placed after the `year` field.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@inproceedings{date2019classical,
    Author = {Date, Prasanna and Schuman, Catherine and Patton, Robert and Potok, Thomas},
    Booktitle = {Future of Inf. and Communication Conf.},
    Pages = {98--117},
    Title = {A Classical-Quantum Hybrid Approach for Unsupervised Probabilistic Machine Learning},
    Year = {2019}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\cite{date2019classical}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```